# How to remove Weekends for computed dates in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am currently facing issues when excluding weekends while computing two dates.

In the below query i am computing two dates this is for eg, when we see there are two dates computed, but I need to exclude weekends. But this solution should be without using any functions

```
SELECT to_date('03-JUN-2019 16:28:03.59283',
               'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS') -  
       to_date('31-MAY-2019 16:28:03.59283',
               'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS') AS day_date 
  from dual
```

Comment: But we want the solution without using oracle functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query and let me know if it works:

```
WITH QRY1 AS
(SELECT TRUNC(to_date('03-JUN-2019 16:28:03.59283', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS')) + LEVEL date_value
   from dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC(to_date('03-JUN-2019 16:28:03.59283', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS')) - 
       TRUNC(TO_DATE('31-MAY-2019 16:28:03.59283', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS')))
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(QRY1.DATE_VALUE, 'DY') NOT IN ('SUN', 'MON') THEN 1
           ELSE 0 END) NO_OF_DAYS_EXCL_WEEKEND
  FROM QRY1;
```

Comment: WITH clause is passing output of 1st (WITH query) as input to the 2nd query. Just substitute "To date" and "From date" in RHS of CONNECT BY clause and "To date" in WITH clause's SELECT column list i.e. "date_value" (column alias).

Comment: Thanks it is working for me, but i need to use this as a subquery to subtract the value . So can i use WITH query to use this value?

Comment: In the above query, take out query enclosed in WITH QRY1 and place it in FROM clause of the outer query. On top of this modified query you can use WITH or make it as sub query of another query.